# android margin for relative layout with different background colors

Tags: android, margin, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout that occupies full screen and has a white background. (fill_parent is set)
I need a margin on the left and right side. The margin area should have a different background color.
How do I set the background color for the margin area?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/c1_cnxlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:background="@color/purewhite" >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another `RelativeLayout` in it, set two different background colors

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/c1_cnxlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/color1" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/c2_cnxlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/color2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This works, however, nested layout containers generally use more
system memory than using a single layout container.

Comment: @Nicks Yes, this may cause some performance issue, but this seems it is  the only way. And I don't think one more layer of a `RelativeLayout` will cause much trouble. You may have a more elegant way?

Comment: I agree,definitely its easier solution for small projects and performance will also not hurt in nesting just a single level. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of border , for any layout can be achieved by using Shape Drawable.
In the case of Relative Layouts margin following can be done:--

Create a margin.xml file in drawable folder.I have added the comments in the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--By default the border shape is rectangle, can be changed using android:shape-->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- This wil be the views background color, where this margin.xml is applied -->
    <solid android:color="@color/view_bg"></solid>

    <!-- Border color and its width is defined by stroke -->
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@color/border_blue"></stroke>

    <!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
    <corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>
    <!--represents the variation of color intensity in a direction represented by angle-->
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="@color/gradient_end"
        android:startColor="@color/gradient_start" />
</shape>
```

and add this in colors.xml file in values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="view_bg">#b20e0f</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="btn_bg">#3e4a56</color>
    <color name="border_blue">#1A237E</color>
    <color name="gradient_start">#FFFF0000</color>
    <color name="gradient_end">#80FF00FF</color>
</resources>
```

and finally in your relativeLayout tag add this:--

```
android:background="@drawable/margin"
```

Refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) for detailed information.